# Dynamic templateUrl in Angular 2 Final

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a single component that can be reused with multiple template urls. For example, I can switch between custom.html, custom1.html, custom2.html as the template urls for the same component using a dynamic input.

I was previously using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380160/4727489), but it doesn't work with Angular 2 final. *A rewrite of that inner content directive without deprecated methods would work for me.*

I've looked at [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html), but can't get anywhere with it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: we can find answer here. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376628/angular-2-4-component-with-dynamic-template-or-templateurl>?