# Angular 2/4 component with dynamic template or templateUrl

Tags: angular, typescript, themes

I have been trying to find a solution for this everywhere.

I have a project with different 'skins', which are basically different sets of templates/Css.

I am trying to have my components use the skin based on a variable THEME_DIR.

Unfortunately, I cannot find how to make that happens. I looked into the [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) on angular.io without success.

I also looked at a few answers here without success either.

Does anyone have an idea?

This is what I tried so far:

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

// @Component({
//     templateUrl: '../../assets/theme/'+THEME_DIR+'/login.template.html',
// })

export class LoginComponent implements, AfterViewInit {


    private log = Log.create('LoginPage');

    constructor(private mzksLsRequestService: MzkLsRequestService,
                private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }



    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(new Component({
            templateUrl: '../../assets/theme/default/login.template.html',
        }));
        let viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();
        let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;
  name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
              private _injector: Injector,
              private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const tmpCmp = Component({
        moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: './e.component.html'})(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      })
  }
}
```

Just make sure that the URL is correct and the template is loaded into the client.

Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I think now my problem is webpack complaining when compiling the templates... I need to find a way around that...

Comment: Just tried on the fresh new Angular cli project, it works fine with webpack. What build process do you use?

Comment: I use an ionic boilerplate. It complains when I put a variable in the template path ( see THEME_DIR in my code) as it seems it doesn't find the right path

Comment: I see, unfortunately I'm not familiar with that. I think you should create another question as it's not really related to the one I answered

Comment: you can also accept or upvote this answer if it helped, thanks

Comment: I did upvoted it :)

I actually fixed it. Somehow the regexp of webpack transpiler would'nt get the concatenation of variable. I used a function and it works perfectly!

Comment: So your code works for very simple template but I cannot seem to inject the rest of the services I uses...

Comment: @millerf, what do you mean `inject the rest of the services`? what services?

Comment: I'll detail it tomorrow. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Let's say I want to use services in the newly created components, or even some directives in the template.

Somehow I cannot get them working. I think it is because the newly created Module doesn't have the right imports, right?

Comment: yes, if you want to use components or directives from another module, just specify them in the imports. if you want to use services, add them to providers. In this line `f.create(this._injector,` you pass the injector from the parent module, so you should be able to access providers from the parent module

Comment: Can I just somwhow retrieve all imports from the parent module and pass them in?

Also, in the class declaration, if I import a NavController for example: 
`
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
                this.log.info('test');
            }
`
I get this:
`
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?).
`

Comment: _Also, in the class declaration_ - what class declaration?

Comment: Or can we just use the parent module directly?
I am using a websocket connexion in one of the service and I cannot have it reinitiated. I would need to use the same service instance.

Comment: by "Class declaration" I mean this line:

`
const tmpCmp = Component({
        moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: './e.component.html'})(class {
    });
`

Comment: so what are you trying to inject there? Where is `NavController` defined? Try using `Inject` like this `constructor(Inject(NavController) navCtrl)` and import `Inject` from the `@angular/core`

Comment: _Can I just somwhow retrieve all imports from the parent module and pass them in?_ - no, you should specify them in the `imports` manually

Comment: can you add the code you're using to the question details?

Comment: You should have all needed here.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/761ce65f25e7bb39c256bb16652a2edb20170731100648/0f96e9
All the code we are interested in is in /src/app/pages/login.compinent.ts
There is 2 questions:
- first is I couldn't inject the navController in the contructor (line 35), I had to do it in a 'hacky' way
- in app.module.ts, I created a 'component' object I tried to re-use line 46 of login.component.ts, in order not to have to re-create the whole list of dependencies...

Thanks a ot for the time oyu spent on that btw...

Comment: @angularindepth-com I managed to get it working, but I still have trouble with AoT. It has been put on the backburner for now, anyway... Do you encounter the same problem?

Comment: @millerf, no, I answered your question :). You didn't accept it so I was wondering if it solved your problem or not

Comment: @angularindepth-com my bad... I actually didn't know you could 'accept' an answer...

Comment: @millerf, thanks for accepting my answer. Yeah, it's a way of telling the author that his solution solved the problem. Upvote is more of a way to say that the solution is good. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to get this partially working on Angular 7 - thanks. However, I don't seem to be able to get any sort of directives working or property bindings in the new template. I get the error: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'p'." Is it possible to get these working? Also seems to strip out any <script> tags in the new template as well. Not sure of a way to sanitize the template using bypassSecurityTrustHtml.

Comment: **** UPDATE: Importing BrowserModule seems to fix the structural directive and property bindings issue

Comment: Was a solution ever shown on how to properly Inject services in the constructor? Following the suggestion above doesn't work and the link to download the sample code is expired. For the time being, I just did the following: "this.cmpRef.instance.parentComponent = this" which allows me to access all services Injected into the 'parentComponent'. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way?

Comment: @azsl1326 can you ask a separate question and post a link here? I'll take a look

Comment: @millerf I am also getting same error regarding the path. It is not able to recognise the path since it is defined in variable. Can you please tell how you fixed this problem?

Comment: I am getting error for property

moduleId: module.id, 

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(18,17): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'

@MaxKoretskyiakaWizard can you please help me? I am using Angular 7.2

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi I've tried your solution but it doesn't works with angular 9 version, it says JIT compilation failed..do you have any idea ?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi I'm trying change url with same component file instead of app.component...

Comment: First I got `Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!`. I fixed it by `import "@angular/compiler";`. Then I got `Error: Component '' is not resolved: templateUrl: ./e.component.html. Did you run and wait for resolveComponentResources()'?`. I can't find how to import / use `resolveComponentResources`. Could you please advise?

Comment: @Halfist Have you found a way how to deal with this `resolveComponentResources` issue?

Comment: @Frimlik, as far as I remember, this only works with `"aot": false` in `angular.json`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem when trying to load dynamicaly templates from the server (i wanted to make security check, translation on server side before serving html.

I've solved it after changing webpack config. In fact, after doing `ng eject`, it created a webpack.config.js which contains a .ts loader `@ngtools/webpack` and :

```
new AotPlugin({
  "mainPath": "main.ts",
  "replaceExport": false,
  "hostReplacementPaths": {
    "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
  },
  "exclude": [],
  "tsConfigPath": "src/main/front/tsconfig.app.json",
  "skipCodeGeneration": true
})
```

This last one, is the origin of the problem. It concerns the AOT (Ahead Of Time). According to the documentation :
ngtools on the options section, it's mentionned :

> skipCodeGeneration. Optional, defaults to false. Disable code
>   generation and do not refactor the code to bootstrap. **This replaces  templateUrl: "string" with template: require("string")**

If you dont want your templateUrl to be compiled AOT, i recommand you to remove the AotPlugin, and to use of the ts-loader instead of @ngtools/webpack see :

[ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

The rule for ts will look like this :

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader'
}
```

Now you can load fresh templates from a relative URL on demand. Example :

```
@Component({
    selector : "custom-component",
    templateUrl : "/my_custom_url_on_server"
})
export class CustomComponent {
}
```

See [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18992)

Comment: ng eject is not longer supported. And I don't recommand this solutions. The idea is to let Angular Compile templates

Answer (score 1):

As of Ivy (I think) we can use static variables (for  example enviroment) in templateUrl.
for example:

```
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    @Component({
        selector: 'home',
        templateUrl: `./skins/${environment.skin}/home.page.html`,
        styleUrls: ['./skins/${environment.skin}/home.page.scss']
    })
```

Comment: Yeah that's cool at compile time, but what about runtime?

Comment: @DARKGuy Did you happen to make it work during runtime?

Comment: @Prabhakaran nope, but I'm not OP either. Not sure if there's a new way to do this as of 2022. There should be...