# Angular 2 dynamic template url with string variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'bancaComponent',
  templateUrl: '{{str}}'
})
export class BancaComponent implements OnInit {
  str: String;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.str = "./file.component.html";
}
```

Is there another way to make it ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this solution :

```
import
{
    Compiler, Component, Injector, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
    ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'bancaComponent',
    template: `<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>`
    // or with a templateUrl
})
export class BancaComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit
{
    @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicTemplate;

    constructor(
        private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>)
    {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        let myTemplateUrl = './file.component.html';

        if (MYCONDITION === MAEXPECTATION)
        {
            myTemplateUrl = './another-template.component.html';
        }

        const tmpCmp = Component({
            moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: myTemplateUrl
        })(class { });
        
        const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class { });

        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
            .then((factories) =>
            {
                const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
                const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
                cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
                this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
            });
    }
}
```

Inspired from : [Angular 2/4 component with dynamic template or templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376628/angular-2-4-component-with-dynamic-template-or-templateurl)

Official source : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: It's edited with a variable and a condition example ;)

Comment: What is the error ? Take a look at the angular official solution for this kind of problem : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @Boulboulouboule
I'm working on Angular 5 and it gives me following error
---
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' myTemplateUrl'

Comment: was anyone able to resolve the error in angular 5+ versions?

Comment: @Boulboulouboule, you are a gem.

Comment: @prabhatgundepalli - I got the same error on Angular 6. Strangely, shorthand property structuring worked for me. 
```const templateUrl: string = this.getTemplateUrl();
{ moduleId: module.id, templateUrl }```

Comment: I was able to get this partially working on Angular 7 - thanks for your help. However, I don't seem to be able to get any sort of directives working or property bindings in the new template. I get the error: 
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'p'." Is it possible to get these working? Also seems to strip out any <script> tags.

Comment: **** UPDATE: Importing BrowserModule seems to fix the structural directive and property bindings issue - NgModule({ imports: [BrowserModule], .........

Comment: @KashifNazar Can you expand upon how you got rid of the Module error? It has started to appear for me and I am not sure how to get rid of it. Thanks!

Comment: It complains when I put a variable in the template pathas it seems it doesn't find the right path .Is there anything extra I need to do ?

Comment: @Boulboulouboule I am getting thiserror  error TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? @azsl1326 that didn't work

Comment: getting this error with angular 9:
https://www.screencast.com/t/HgRuD3fKD

Comment: First I got `Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!`. I fixed it by `import "@angular/compiler";`. Then I got `Error: Component '' is not resolved: templateUrl: ./another-template.component.html. Did you run and wait for resolveComponentResources()'?`. I can't find how to import / use `resolveComponentResources`. Could you please advise?

Comment: There should be a working solution for this in 2021, anyone got any?

Answer (score 0):

## Angular 13

Create multiple components with the desired templates, then load the components in dynamically like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit
{
    @ViewChild('dynamic', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
    public dynamicContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    ngAfterContentInit()
    {
        const myComponentInstance = this.dynamicContainer.createComponent(MyComponent);
    }
}
```

[source](https://medium.com/@damodara.puddu/when-to-use-angulars-dynamic-components-ce40db069359)