# How to dynamically change html file being used in component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have different html files which should be triggered depending on a condition. However, I should be using just one typescript file for everything. Is this possible to do? Ideally, the value of `templateUrl` will be changed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: 'template1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['appprofile.component.css']
})
```

Comment: The `@Component` decorator is executed before the component is instantiated, so if your plan is to change it based on your components properties, it's not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 dynamic template url with string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133024/angular-2-dynamic-template-url-with-string-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. The only way that comes to my mind without creating another component or dynamic component loading is to switch template fragments via `*ngIf`.