# how to change the template html dynamically

Tags: angular

I am using a dynamic component in my angular app. It's working fine but I want to change the html template it uses, For example in my dynamic component.ts I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: '<p>Stackoverflow</p>' ,
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic.component.css']
})
```

So in the decorator instead of a html string can I use a variable which I get from some other service that holds required html string ? like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: variablehavinghtml,
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic.component.css']
})
```

I tried using templateUrl to link a html which has a div like:

```
<div [innerHTML]="variablehavinghtml"></div>
```

but as my variable can also have tags with angular property bindings it's not working so I have to give the html string inside my component decorator. So how can I do this?

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133024/angular-2-dynamic-template-url-with-string-variable

Comment: @Zero is there an angular 8 version of this?

Answer (score 0):

You could either enable angular routing, and the just redirect to all the app bodies you need, or you can define all the possible components in `app.component` and just display them if on a correct route:

`import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';` in `app.component.ts`

`constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute) { }` to initialise the routing.

Let's create a variable r that will keep the first route parameter:

Place `this.route.pathFromRoot[1].url.subscribe(val => { this.r = val.toString(); });` in `ngOnInit()`

In your html code, if you're at `localhost:4200/forum` as an example, and you want to have something only your forum will contain, you can do:

```html
<div *ngIf="input == 'forum'">
    <!-- Content here will be only displayed on the forum route -->
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: the actual app is far more complex, I represented in a simple way and yes it has multiple routing modules, but my requirement is to display a html in the same path. I get lot of html strings so I can't possibly create routes for each of them.

Comment: Oh! I see! So you want to stay on the same route, but change the contents of the page?

An example would be [Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp) (Go down to _Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs_; you'll have to import jQuery for this one) But something like that would work.

Comment: It's not about changing contents, more about displaying them as I mentioned I have to display html that has tags with angular property bindings. Something like this [https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-raw-template] but I don't want to create an NgModule in the component ts.