# How to load conditionally templateUrl html file in Angular 5 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular5

There is one scenario in my project,
Consider, I have one testDynamic component

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "./test-dynamic.html", // Need to override this file
    styleUrls: ['./test-dynamic.css']
})
export class testDynamic {
    constructor() { }
}
```

here need to check if an override1.html file is exists in override folder then load this file as templateUrl otherwise load the component default test-dynamic.html. 
Any idea how to achieve this.?

refer the following image for clearly understanding

[image]

Comment: You will check the below: <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2%5B/link%5D

Comment: @GSK Thanks, I read you shared link and tried on localhost but almost all solutions are not working with Angular 5.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376628/angular-2-4-component-with-dynamic-template-or-templateurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add more than one HTML file.

What you can do is, use *ngIf or *ngSwitchCase to show only parts of the template if that is your intention. Then you have only one template html file.

Then html of your template will be something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="YOUR_CONDITION">View 01</div>
<div *ngIf="YOUR_CONDITION">View 02</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work for me because we are building a framework on Angular and this is one scenario to provide template overriding facility to users.

One question is it possible before AOT?