# Angular Can't resolve template - Conditonal templateUrl

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const template = environment.production ? '../dev/dev-app.component.html' : './app.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: template,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

In the above I am trying to write a conditional variable called `template` which will load the view for the component.

Only I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' template' in '/src/app'

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just a conditional html viewdepending on env

Comment: You cannot load template dynamically like that. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377048/1791913

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2/4 component with dynamic template or templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376628/angular-2-4-component-with-dynamic-template-or-templateurl)