# Angular - How to load templateUrl dynamically?

Tags: angular

I have to build an application which supports dynamic template rendering.
For example, consider following templates for landing page.

**theme1/home.html**

```
<div>Welcome ${name}!</div>
```

**theme2/home.html**

```
<div>Welcome ${name}!</div>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  inventore</p>
```

If user 'A' logs in, theme1/home.html should be rendered whereas for user 'B', theme2/home.html should be rendered.

I have to maintain 10-15 themes in my application and particular theme should be rendered based on logged in user dynamically.

If I make the templateUrl dynamic by appending the variable path to filename as follows, its not working.

```
templateUrl: pathToThemeFolder + '/home.html'
```

Please suggest how to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Why don't you load component base on the current user ?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377048/6804648

Comment: You can define routes as per diff theme and redirect user to specific route based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

To Implement such a dynamic scenario you need to save theme detail on backend side with the user.

API by which you are checking for a valid user, get theme details as well in the response of API and based on it you can load the theme.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic scenario needs template url ( use API services) Httpclientservice directive and import data(themes) and export themes of based on API key