# How to add variable in Angular templateurl

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I wanted to load vendor specific html template for my component. Below is a code snippet. Problem is, I am getting resolved text string as an output instead of actual template. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Code Snippet:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

const helplineTemplate: string = './vendors/helpline.'+environment.vendor_prefix+'.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-helpline',
  templateUrl: helplineTemplate,
  styleUrls: ['./helpline.component.css']
})
export class HelplineComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Output which I am getting:

```
./vendors/helpline.google.component.html
```

here google is variable which is coming from environment file. `environment.vendor_prefix`

This is probably not a duplicate question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376628/angular-2-4-component-with-dynamic-template-or-templateurl). I am actually trying to understand the strange behaviour. Although its a `templateUrl`, it is still behaving like `template`. Also the variable value is getting resolved before compiler hits class decorator.

Comment: Can you explain `I am getting resolved text string as an output instead` what that means.

Comment: @Reactgular, I am expecting the content inside `./vendors/helpline.google.component.html` file to get rendered on screen. However I am just getting plain text as ./vendors/helpline.google.component.html on screen.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `templateUrl` and not `template`?

Comment: yes. The code is copy pasted here as it is.